# Use Jquery to prevent page reloading pressing anchor

Tags: php, jquery, process, reload

I am trying to use the jquery to Prevent page realoading. I have the whole code php done... and is functional. if you can please go to http://www.jonathansconstruction.com/gallery3.php and click on the different gallery SUbmenus for category View All, Kitchen etc... i'm using get for variables. However, I would like to use a jquery to process the php so i dont have to include it into the gallery.php and also, to prevent page reloading because it brings the page back up and that could be confusing. Any hlep willl be greatly appreciated THanks

UPDATE, Thanks for everyone that helped:

SO far i made an advance on the website, Corrected URL was edited on top of the post

Everything is working smoothly on the effects of quicksand.. HOwever, Lytebox Doesn't Load when a quicksand effect is placed. , at the beginning it loads just fine, but right after pressing one of the menus for the quicksand effect. It stops working.  Also, I want to style my menu buttons as is in http://www.jonathansconstruction.com/gallery.php. I see jquery doesnt add  and

witht the sample I downloaded. and also the  that says "gallery Pictures" dissapears ont he quicksand demo.

Any Help is appreciated. Below is the script.js code I have modified so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var items = $('.photo_show figure'),
    itemsByTags = {};

// Looping though all the li items:

items.each(function(i){
    var elem = $(this),
        tags = elem.data('tags').split(',');

    // Adding a data-id attribute. Required by the Quicksand plugin:
    elem.attr('data-id',i);

    $.each(tags,function(key,value){

        // Removing extra whitespace:
        value = $.trim(value);

        if(!(value in itemsByTags)){
            // Create an empty array to hold this item:
            itemsByTags[value] = [];
        }

        // Each item is added to one array per tag:
        itemsByTags[value].push(elem);
    });

});

// Creating the "Everything" option in the menu:
createList('View All',items);

// Looping though the arrays in itemsByTags:
$.each(itemsByTags,function(k,v){
    createList(k,v);
});

$('#gallery_menu nav a').live('click',function(e){
    var link = $(this);

    link.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');

    // Using the Quicksand plugin to animate the li items.
    // It uses data('list') defined by our createList function:

    $('.photo_show').quicksand(link.data('list').find('figure'), {adjustHeight: 'dynamic'} );
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#gallery_menu nav a:first').click();

function createList(text,items){

    // This is a helper function that takes the
    // text of a menu button and array of li items

    // Creating an empty unordered list:
    var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':'hidden'});

    $.each(items,function(){
        // Creating a copy of each li item
        // and adding it to the list:

        $(this).clone().appendTo(ul);
    });

    ul.appendTo('.photo_show');

    // Creating a menu item. The unordered list is added
    // as a data parameter (available via .data('list'):

    var a = $('<a>',{
        html: text,
        href:'#',
        data: {list:ul}
    }).appendTo('#gallery_menu nav');
}
  });
```

ANOTHER EDIT :

All Looking good So far Fixed Lot of problems, However, for some reason, the span I had on teh static html dissapears from display and even html code when loading jquery quicksand code..?? Here is the code i have on the html part of the website that Does Not appear on the live website for some reason.

```
<div id="portfolio">
                <div class="photo_show"><span>Gallery Pictures</span>
```

the span part doesnt appear, dont know why

I had the TOp Part Resolvd. just moved the  on top of photo_show div and edited positioning... HOPEFULLY Last Edit 
 the jquery for quicksand made my calendar dissapear, checked and yes it was some jquery conflict but dont know what can be causing it.. also the form validation not working as well ...  any help is appreciated!

Comment: put some HTML markup in your post. only description doesn't make sense.

Comment: Bind functions to the `onclick` event. Set anchor tag href's to `javscript:void(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited your webpage link after correcting a **typo** in the URL for word `construction`.

I also see the problem that the page **reloads when clicking** on a `sorting filter` such as **View All**, **Kitchen**, and **Miscellaneous** which is what you want to prevent.

Unfortunately, those buttons are using `URL Links` *asking* to reload the webpage with a filtered option via query string. Nothing can be done for that method of filtering, your just going to reload the webpage since filtering is done on page load.

Perhaps this [DEMO](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/) shows what you want to accomplish since it does not reload the webpage. That demo has markup that is easy to create and maintain which is build using the **[Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) jQuery Plugin**. The tutorial for that demo is accessed using the link at the bottom right, but looking at the source HTML file shows how simple it is.

I made a downloadable demo using both **Quicksand and Shadowbox**, a lightbox alternative [HERE](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Quicksand-Demo-featuring-Shadowbox-tp7303500.html), which might interest you since your webpage is linking the filtered icon results to a lightbox alternative named [Lytebox](http://lytebox.com/index.php).

Since your edit reflects your interest in **Lytebox**, the following markup will **reinitialize** that lightbox alternative after a filtering event has occurred with Quicksand. Update your **script.js** file accordingly.

```
$('.photo_show').quicksand(link.data('list').find('figure'), function(){

    adjustHeight = 'dynamic';
    initLytebox();

});
```

I also made a correction to your existing **adjustHeight** since it was using a semicolon instead of an equal sign, but the correct location and use of that is for something unrelated.

The reason that you are not seeing the **bullets** is because your not using `ul/li tags` that the demo is using.

Comment: Thank you, THis is what i want to accomplish, however, i was looking at the source code, and i do need to access the php side because the information for the portfolio needs to be done via mysql. since thats why i have the php in order to access the information for category menus and pictres I'm reading more about it but any other elp is appreciated because i'm very new with jquery

Comment: I manage to do what i want ina  away but however, when i change it to my regular website, it doesnt work, any ideas? here is the one working http://jconstruction.us.cloudlogin.co/portifolio/

Comment: @artronics, Please Read My question edited on top... need very little to finish it..

Comment: @artronics, Thanks for the help, yes i am interested in lytebox because i have it all setup with that plugin and i want to change the less code possible. the edit worked perfectly I don't know however why cant i see the <span></Span> i put statically under that photo_show div.. and how to do it, as well as the menu, i'm not so sure yet either to style it as before, or create teh <ul> and li tags accordingly as i have it on my previous menu

Comment: @artronics, yes I had taht resolved.. I should've open a new css but well, it wasnt really big question i thought. Anyway, can you tell me why the calendar dissapeared? i checked my elements and seems some jquery conflict ?? i'm not sure...

Comment: yes , should i open another so question? i thought it could be related. since without the quicksand script the calendar appears well, with it, it doesnt' and for the jquery validation.. well, i need jquery 1.6.1 for quicksand to run fine, else, with the other jquery versions i have it doesnt run, dont know why though.. i thought it was related since the quicksand is doing that...

Comment: did you check html validator or css validator on w3c? I do find 2 erros on w3c for html but just facebook parsing wich i guess can't do much about it.. , and how about the validation function?.. is that w3c errors too?.. if it is not the html validator tell me which one u used so i can correct them

Comment: Ok one last question, for some reason quicksand Plugin not working in IE 7, well it works but messes up  the display